# Drop unnamed Foreign Key in MySql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

If a foreign key was created without a name, MySql will give it a default one. For instance, for table 'Test' the foreign key will be named 'test_ibfk_1'. When I drop the foreign key locally by using this name it works like a charm but on the development server it fails with errno: 152.

I know this name is case sensitive but either lower or upper case the result is the same.

My question: Is it safe to rely on the default name to manipulate constraints (in MySql at least)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to know the name of foreign key. If it was created without name, then name will be autogenerated. You should get information about the foreign key.

Use one of these queries to get foreign key names -

```
SELECT
  constraint_name
FROM
  information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
  constraint_schema = <'db_name'> AND table_name = <'table_name'>;


SELECT *
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  constraint_schema = <'db_name'> AND table_name = <'table_name'> AND   
  referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
```

...and use `ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP INDEX <fk_name>;` to drop foreign key.

Comment: Is the above query applicable to non-admins? Overall very good to know info! Thanks!

Comment: It's a shame to have to go through this endurance trek, just to get your fk_name for this kind of query. It should have been straightforward to say: `ALTER table table_name DROP CONSTRAINT ON col_name` (no matter what name it bears). Afterall, there can only be one such constraint on a given key. Right everyone?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo, I agree completely.  It's especially problematic if you're using something like Liquibase to manage schema changes across multiple environments' databases, and they aren't guaranteed to generate the same FK constraint name on every database on which they're run.  This means you can't rely on that constraint name in future changes.  Though you could obviously start naming constraints with a fixed name from the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

Hurried reader, **don't go away from this answer, just because it's long. You won't find another solution**, I promise :)

The accepted answer does not drop the key, it only finds its name. To actually drop the key with an unknown name, you'll need to use prepared statements. The most general solution is this script that you can customize with five variables:

```
-- YOU MUST SPECIFY THESE VARIABLES TO FULLY IDENTIFY A CONSTRAINT
SET @table_name = '...';
SET @column_name = '...';
SET @referenced_table_name = '...';
SET @referenced_column_name = '...';
-- make sure to limit queries to a single db schema
SET @db_name = '...'; 

-- find the name of the foreign key and store it in a var
SET @constraint_name = (
    SELECT constraint_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
        AND COLUMN_NAME = @column_name
        AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @db_name
        AND referenced_table_name = @referenced_table_name
        AND referenced_column_name = @referenced_column_name);


-- prepare the drop statement in a string and run it
SET @s = concat('alter table ', @table_name, ' drop foreign key ', @constraint_name);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could remove without know the name, creating a concatenate query and executing automatically:

```
set @s:='';
select @s:=concat(@s, 'alter table ', 'your_table', ' drop foreign key ',CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';')
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'your_database'
  and TABLE_NAME ='your_table'
  and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'the_foreign_reference_table';
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;

deallocate prepare stmt;
```

I that way you don't need to know the name of the foreign key, only need the table_name which you want to remove the foreign key, the database name and the reference table.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested on how to **drop ALL foreign keys** from a table, we use this code in our update stored procedure (the example is applied on table db_Order from our internal database):

```
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE foreignKeyDeleteStatement VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '';

...

SET counter = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name='db_Order');
    SELECT 'Number of foreignKeys on table db_Order = ' + counter;

WHILE counter > 0 DO
                SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';') 
                FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
                WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
                AND TABLE_NAME='db_order' 
                AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
                LIMIT 1
                INTO foreignKeyDeleteStatement;
                
                SELECT foreignKeyDeleteStatement;
                
                SET @s = foreignKeyDeleteStatement;
        
                PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
                EXECUTE stmt1;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
                
                SET counter = counter - 1;
END WHILE;
```

I hope this is useful to someone.