# How to make this SQL using REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME work in H2

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, h2, liquibase, information-schema

I was in a situation where the only way to drop a foreign key constraint was [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541719/925913);

```
-- YOU MUST SPECIFY THESE VARIABLES TO FULLY IDENTIFY A CONSTRAINT
SET @table_name = '...';
SET @column_name = '...';
SET @referenced_table_name = '...';
SET @referenced_column_name = '...';
-- make sure to limit queries to a single db schema
SET @db_name = '...'; 

-- find the name of the foreign key and store it in a var
SET @constraint_name = (
    SELECT constraint_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
        AND COLUMN_NAME = @column_name
        AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @db_name
        AND referenced_table_name = @referenced_table_name
        AND referenced_column_name = @referenced_column_name);

-- prepare the drop statement in a string and run it
SET @s = concat('alter table ', @table_name, ' drop foreign key ', @constraint_name);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I'm running these statements via Liquibase. The above worked for MySQL, but did not for H2. The error being,

```
SEVERE 2/23/21, 12:18 PM: liquibase: adaccount.sql: adaccount.sql::53::acheong: Change Set adaccount.sql::53::acheong failed.
Error: Column "REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME" not found; SQL statement:
SET @constraint_name = (
    SELECT constraint_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
        AND COLUMN_NAME = @column_name
        AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @db_name
        AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = @referenced_table_name
        AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = @referenced_column_name) [42122-196] [Failed SQL: SET @constraint_name = (
    SELECT constraint_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
        AND COLUMN_NAME = @column_name
        AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @db_name
        AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = @referenced_table_name
        AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = @referenced_column_name)]
INFO 2/23/21, 12:18 PM: liquibase: adaccount.sql::53::acheong: Successfully released change log lock
```

Not sure if I'm looking at the correct reference, but it seems `referenced_table_name` might not be [a thing in H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html).

**Is there a way I can tweak this prepared statement to work for both MySQL and H2?**

Note: The foreign key is unnamed so I can't use a simple `ALTER TABLE ... DROP FOREIGN KEY`. I also can't use `dropForeignKeyContraint` because I'm stuck with a non-XML, SQL-only config. I have looked into several other ways too—unfortunately the user in [the aforementioned solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541719/925913) is quite right—there isn't another way that works.

---

#### Edit

Thanks to @EvgenijRyazanov I've gotten a little farther. I upgraded to H2 1.4.200 so that `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` became available, and joined `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`. The inner query works as expected in MySQL:

[image]

However the same inner query in H2 appears to return 0 results (empty string):

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE audit_event DROP FOREIGN KEY [*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE audit_event DROP FOREIGN KEY  [42001-200] [Failed SQL: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @s]
```

Comment: You're.using an old version of H2, it doesn't have this table at all, and these additional non-standard columns are MySQL-specific, in H2 (recent versions) and others this information is located in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table, so you need to join it, MySQL has it too. Also even the latest version of H2 supports only `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, but MySQL doesn't support it (MariaDB does). So hypothetically you can write and use the same SQL for H2 1.4.200 and MariaDB, but for H2 1.4.196 and MySQL it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenijRyazanov ! You should make this an answer because it's already helped me. I realized I didn't need the `REFERENCED_*` conditions so I removed them. Then I had a syntax error at `PREPARE` which you prepared me for (; I upgraded to 1.4.200 and used `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Now I think we're past that, but I see `Column "constraint_name" not found;` so I'm diving into that.

Comment: Okay, I was able to join to the table you mentioned. (See edit to question.) However I'm not seeing the inner query return a constraint in H2...

Comment: Update: It was because H2 and MySQL don't seem to agree on what a CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA is. In MySQL it was the database name. In H2 it's the string "PUBLIC". Relaxing that constraint successfully identified the foreign key I needed. Again, if you wanna paste your comment to an answer, happy to accept!